# Magento admin and operations questions

Tags: discussion, suitable-question

I'm a mod over on Stack Overflow. We get a fair number of non-programming questions about deploying, upgrading, administering Magento and one or two other eCommerce/Cart apps.

Quite often these get flagged for migration to Webmasters, I've been closing them as off-topic.

These questions are **purely about Magento** and not about managing or administering a website that happens to have Magento as its primary application.

I'm asking for some clarification from your community about whether these are on-topic here or not and whether I should open the flood gates.

Answer (score 6):

Although they aren't a perfect fit for this website, we generally allow questions that are specifically about a piece of software as long as it is not subjective, low quality, or a better fit at another SE site (i.e. drupal, wordpress). So if you feel those questions  meet the above criteria then migrate them over to Pro Webmasters and we'll do our best to answer them.

Comment: +1 though it would be nice if the people at SO able to answer those Magento-programming questions also occasionally followed these here to help with them(I'm assuming being able to code for Magento, they can also administer it,etc.) The questions are *allowed*, and from an organizational perspective they do seem to fit here better, but from [what I see](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento) they don't usually get too much engagement.